# Website blocker continues to block websites after stopping process

Tags: python, python-3.9

I coded a website blocker that would block certain websites. Once I run the script, the websites are blocked. The issue I am facing is that despite stopping the process I am still unable to access the websites. In other words, the websites are still blocked after I terminate the program. here is my code:

```
import time
import os
os.chdir("C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/")
file = open('hosts', 'w')
hosts_path = "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"

website_blocked = ["www.facebook.com", "facebook.com", "www.twitter.com", "twitter.com", "www.instagram.com"
    , "instagram.com"]

while True:
    if 1 == 1:
        print("Working Blocked")
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in website_blocked:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")
    else:
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in website_blocked):
                    file.write(line)

            file.truncate()

        print("Website Allowed")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I would like to know how I can make the website blocker stop blocking the website after the process has been stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) to add cleanup function to your script which unblocks the sites.

```
def unblock(hosts_path,website_blocked):
    with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)
        for line in content:
            if not any(website in line for website in website_blocked):
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()
    
import atexit
atexit.register(unblock, hosts_path, website_blocked)
```